# Show Modified and Created columns with Date only

Tags: list, document-library, column, library

I'm looking for the best way (if there is one) to show the *Modified* and *Created* columns in a list/library with the date only, so without the time. For example, instead of *1/12/2011 8:37 PM* it should show *1/12/2011* only. This should not happen on the whole farm/web app/site collection/site, but only for specific lists/libraries.

Things that I thought of so far

- Adding a calculated column to the specific list/library, that takes the Modifed/Created column's value, and simply reformats to show the date only. Benefit: easy to implement. Drawback: Columns are no longer called Modified/Created. Not reusable, needs to be reimplemented each time
- create a jQuery solution that hides the time on the client side. Benefit: easily reusable, columns are still named Modifed/Created. Drawback: jQuery code reference needs to be added to each view
- update the Modified/Created column of the individual list/library to display date only through server-side code. Benefit: Columns are updated properly. Drawback: Not even sure if it's possible to update the formatting? Will the time be lost? Will sorting still work properly?

My preference is #1 at the moment, as it isn't even clear yet how large the scope if this will be (could even be just a few lists/libraries, but might end up with thousands as well).

Are there any other things I need to consider? Anything else that I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 2):

I would also use the calculated column. It's the most easy solution...

Also, if you use jQuery and you migrate to a newer version of sharepoint it could be that your jQuery won't work anymore. (+ you could get a visible change for users with slow computer > since you run this client-side)

Answer (score 1):

use the third option:

```
$web = get-spweb http://thingy/
$list = $web.lists["List Name"]
$datefield = $list.fields["Date Field"]
$datefield.displayformat = [microsoft.sharepoint.spdatetimefieldformattype]::dateonly
$datefield.update()
```

No need to worry about data loss or sorting - the data's still held in a `DateTime` object, just displayed differently. I actually ran this on my site column instead of the list column, which seems a little bit dangerous because this column is used universally, but nothing has broken yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a calculated column and you migrate to a newer version of SharePoint, it's more likely that that won't work.  (Content Type-Need I say more).  Microsoft is less backward compatible than ANY sofware manufacturer BY FAR!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a calculated calculate column called ModifiedDateOnly and give it the formula:

```
=TEXT([Modified],"MM/dd/yyyy").
```

The C# date text formatters seem to work although I haven't tried them all.

[SharePoint Validation TEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-4b46e545-e612-4c84-ac23-edfa68007945)

[C# DateTime String Formatters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)